# How can I properly format NStimer in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a timer in Swift and I can't figure out how the format works with NStimer. I want to output the time in 00 format, so when it increases it goes like: 00 -> 01 -> 02 ->.....-> 10 -> 11 -> ...
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


@IBOutlet var label : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label_c : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var button : UIButton!
var count : Double = 0.0
var time : NSTimer!

@IBAction func countI(){
    time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "countS", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func countS(){
    count += 0.01
    let s = String(format: "%02d", count%100)
    label.text = toString(count)
    label_c.text = s
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: im not sure how does the String(format: "%02d", xxxx) works. for mine
label_c.text = s 
this outputs 00 and it doesn't change 
label.text = toString(count) 
it outputs number but it is not in the format i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a type error — `%d` expects an integer but you're passing in a double.

You can just cast the result to an `Int` and that should work:

```
let s = String(format: "%02d", Int(count%100))
```

Comment: `%.2f` means a double to 2 decimal places, so something like "3.14". It sounds like you want leading zero integers like 00 and 09 and 20 so `%02d` is correct, just with the integer cast.